# Handshake failed on some android devices

Tags: android, rest, https, retrofit

On some device i have no problems with a communication with the server used with the retrofit framework. I also used several Android versions to verify that the code run. But on some devices (Samsung S8) I got each time an error: 'Handshake failed'. Does anybody have an idea where is the problem? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
protected static Retrofit getInstanceWithoutToken() {
    final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            final Request original = chain.request();
            final Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(CommonConstantsRest.REST_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the client and the server couldn't agree on a protocol and cipher suite to use. Have you tried adding a [logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to see if you can get more details about the problem?

Comment: @Michael thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I got only the same message: `D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed` and again only on the specific device (it is on several devices of this type so i don't think that the problem is on the device

Comment: If you can set up a virtual wifi hotspot on your computer and connect the phone to the internet through that, you could log the TLS handshake on your computer using Wireshark.

Comment: Does this problem happen on a specific version of anroid ?

Comment: @xiaomi not on specific version on android but on specific devices

Comment: im facing the same problem now, with Some Samsung devices, regardless the OS, even Android 10, any news?

Comment: @finalpets see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the ssl communication. Adding the following CipherSuite solved the problem

```
protected static Retrofit getInstanceWithoutToken() {
    ConnectionSpec spec = new
            ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .build();
    final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    httpClient.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
    httpClient
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            final Request original = chain.request();
            final Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(CommonConstantsRest.REST_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();
}
```